# Unable to get location of object present in screen - Appium (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, appium, webdriver-io

I'm unable to get location of element present in *Android* screen with *Appium*.

I checked documentation about getLocation() method on http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/location/ but I didn't get the information of element location.

I tried with entire object:

```
console.log("Get location object: " + driver.getLocation('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("io.appium.android.apis:id/text"))'));
```

And with specific value (X):

```
console.log("Get location parameter 'x': " + driver.getLocation('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("io.appium.android.apis:id/text"))').x);
```

I expect X and Y values from response but I'm receiving following values in console:

> Get location object: `[object Object]`
>
> Get location parameter 'x': `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I think the docs have an incorrect example. It should be working like [this](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/getLocation.html):

```
const text = browser.$('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("io.appium.android.apis:id/text"))')
const location = text.getLocation();
console.log(location); // outputs: { x: ..., y: ... }
```

You first need to get an element object, then use its API to get the location.

`browser.getLocation()` is to get GPS coordinates

Comment: I can't use $ selector, instead of that I used:    

`const text =  driver.getLocation('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("io.appium.android.apis:id/text"))');
const location = text.getLocation();
console.log(location); `

And I got this on console **[Object Object]**

Comment: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/61754a87e42e381f0b955626f8f420adcc97160c/packages/webdriverio/tests/commands/element/getLocation.test.js#L12

Comment: I edited code to match with your instructions but and I still receiving  [Object Object], I research about this and implement JSON.parse in order to try to read JSON object (due to that is the expected on result based on documentation: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/location#response) but I'm receiving "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" error message.

Comment: And this is the code:

const text = driver.$('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("io.appium.android.apis:id/text"))')
const location = text.getLocation();
console.log('location' + location); 
var obj = JSON.parse(location);
console.log(obj)

Comment: Can you try like this: const xLocation = text.getLocation('x');
    console.log(xLocation); // outputs: 150

Comment: I added this code: 

`const xLocation = text.getLocation('x'); `
`console.log('xLocation value:' + xLocation);`

And I received this:
`xLocation value:[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Appium Studio. With that its pretty simple to get the location of the element

```
String locationX = client.elementGetProperty("NATIVE", "your-xpath-here", 0, "X");
String locationY = client.elementGetProperty("NATIVE", "your-xpath-here", 0, "Y");
```

This is to get the X and Y co-ordinates respectively. For detailed explanation, you can have a look at the documentation [here](https://experitest.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TE/pages/3077165/ElementGetProperty).

Comment: Thank you for your surgery but actually I'm facing to get location of element on javascript, they are using Java.